# How to intercept a touch event and forward to a specified UIView

Tags: ios, ios4, uiscrollview

I have transparent `UIView` (we'll call it `receiver`) layered over a `UIScrollView` (`scrollView`) which has a `UIScrollViewDelegate` (`scrollViewDelegate`).

In some situations, `receiver` needs to consume the touch events which land on it. In others, I need to glean some positional information and then either pass the touch events intact through to `scrollView` or alternatively spoof the events which would comprise a drag movement and result in the appropriate deceleration etc. How can I achieve this?

---

**EDIT - Research thus far:**

I've put a breakpoint inside `scrollViewDelegate`'s `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, which reveals the call sequence to be:

```
(...various calls filtering down from UIApplicationMain...)
[UIWindow sendEvent:]
[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:]
...
[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture:]
[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent]
_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
[UIScrollView handlePan:]
[UIScrollView _updatePanGesture]
....
[UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewWillBeginDragging:]
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to call into `UIScrollView handlePan:` with the appropriate information, but I can't find anything which details how to correctly call `handlePan` (I assume it must be possible, since `_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions` does it?).

Alternatively I suppose I could subclass `UIGestureRecognizer`, but this seems a pretty heavy handed way of doing it (and again I have no idea how to communicate the sequence of touch events).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to place your `UIScrollView` inside of your receiver.

You can then do one of two things:

- Set `userInteractionsEnabled` on your scroll view to `NO` if you know ahead-of-time that the events shouldn't be delivered to it. The events will be delivered to your receiver view instead.
- Override `hitTest:withEvent:` to note the incoming events. To squelch them, just return your receiver (indicating that it should be the target of those events); to pass them along, return the value from super's implementation (which will correctly identify the scroll view as the target when appropriate).

If you really need to synthesize events, you can construct them and pass them to `UIApplication`'s `- (void)sendEvent:` method. (Calling `handlePan:` directly probably won't work, since it takes a `UIGestureRecognizer` and so will be hard to fake.)

Comment: Excellent, this looks like exactly what I need - will code it up and get back to you. Cheers :)